# vb.net error using interface

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, interface

I am getting this error

> "Error    19  Class 'LegacyRouteHandler' must implement 'Function
>   GetHttpHandler(requestContext As RequestContext) As IHttpHandler' for
>   interface 'System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler'."

from this code:

```
Public Class LegacyRouteHandler
    Implements IRouteHandler
    Public Function GetHttpHandler(requestContext As RequestContext) As IHttpHandler
        Return New LegacyHandler(requestContext)
    End Function
End Class
```

I am clearly implementing `GetHttpHandler` , any ideas why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an `Implements` clause after the function prototype.

```
...) As IHttpHandler Implements IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler
'                    ^
```

VB.NET doesn't automatically wire up functions to their interface definitions like C# does.

Comment: That's lame , i'm still getting used to these little differences in vb.net - thanks